# Update Array of Documents, deleting all but the 3 best scores in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to update all my Documents so that they only have the 3 highest scored opinions but i don't know how to do it. Here's my example:

```
{
_id:9787878,
name: "Restaurant Manolo",
scores: [ 
         {grade:8, opinion:"Very good"},
         {grade:1, opinion:"Bad"},
         {grade:10, opinion:"Very good"},
         {grade:2, opinion:"Bad"},
         {grade:6, opinion:"Very good"},
        ]
}
```

I want to update the document so it looks like this:

```
{
_id:9787878,
name: "Restaurant Manolo",
scores: [ 
         {grade:10, opinion:"Very good"},
         {grade:8, opinion:"Very good"},
         {grade:6, opinion:"Very good"},
        ]
}
```

Any idea what type of Query should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`$sort with $slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#use-sort-with-other-push-modifiers) modifier.

```
db.col.update(
   { name: "Restaurant Manolo" },
   { $push: { scores: { $each: [ ], $sort:  { grade: -1 }, $slice: 3 } } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.server.updateMany(
  {}, // all documents
  { 
    $set : {
      scores : {
        $sort: { grade: 1 }, // low->high
        $slice: -3 // keep last 3
      }
    }
  }
);
```